# datagridview using cellpainting but don't work exactly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

There is a DataGridView with over 60 columns in winform and using the CellPainting event.
When scrolling horizontally, the borders become thinner or inconsistently thick.
And this problem only happened when scrolling horizontally.
I'm not sure if the issue is caused by the re-painting.
I had used DoubleBuffered already.
I tried several ways still can't solve this problem.Please help me.

My code：

```
private void dgvSetting_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
            return;

        if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex < 13 || e.ColumnIndex == 20 || e.ColumnIndex == 23 || e.ColumnIndex == 31 || e.ColumnIndex == 35 || e.ColumnIndex == 38 || e.ColumnIndex == 47)
            {
                e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

                using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
                {
                    Rectangle rect = e.CellBounds;
                    rect.X = rect.Right - 1;
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.X, rect.Bottom);
                }

                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Background);

        DataGridViewRow row = dgvWSettingAll.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        DataGridViewCell cellMarketType = row.Cells["ColMarketType"];
        DataGridViewCell cellWType = row.Cells["ColWType"];

        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 14 && cellMarketType.Value.ToString() != "S")
        {
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
            {
                Rectangle rect = e.CellBounds;

                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Left, rect.Bottom);

            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 20 || e.ColumnIndex == 23 || e.ColumnIndex == 31 || e.ColumnIndex == 35 || e.ColumnIndex == 38 || e.ColumnIndex == 47)
        {
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
            {
                Rectangle rect = e.CellBounds;
                rect.X = rect.Right - 1;

                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, rect.X, rect.Top, rect.X, rect.Bottom);
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }


        if (cellMarketType.Value != null && cellMarketType.Value.ToString() == "S" && e.ColumnIndex > 13)
        {
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
            {
                Rectangle rect = e.CellBounds;
                rect.Y = rect.Top;

                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, rect.Left, rect.Y, rect.Right, rect.Y);

                if (e.ColumnIndex == 20 || e.ColumnIndex == 23 || e.ColumnIndex == 31 || e.ColumnIndex == 35 || e.ColumnIndex == 38 || e.ColumnIndex == 47)
                {
                    rect.X = rect.Right - 1;
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, rect.X, rect.Top, rect.X, rect.Bottom);
                }
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if (e.RowIndex == 0 && e.ColumnIndex < 13)
        {
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
            {
                Rectangle rect = e.CellBounds;
                rect.X = rect.Right - 1;

                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, rect.X, rect.Top, rect.X, rect.Bottom);
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }


        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex > 13 && e.ColumnIndex < 19 && cellWType.Value.ToString() != "All")
        {

            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);


            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
            {
                Rectangle rect = e.CellBounds;
                rect.X = rect.Right - 1;

                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, rect.X, rect.Top, rect.X, rect.Bottom);
            }

            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
            {
                Rectangle rect = e.CellBounds;
                rect.Y = rect.Top;
                rect.Height = 2;

                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Top);
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 19 && (cellWType.Value.ToString() == "All" || cellMarketType.Value.ToString() == "WI"))
        {
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
            {
                Rectangle rect = e.CellBounds;
                rect.X = rect.Right - 1;

                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, rect.X, rect.Top, rect.X, rect.Bottom);
            }

            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
            {
                Rectangle rect = e.CellBounds;
                rect.Y = rect.Top;
                rect.Height = 2;

                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Top);
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }


    private void dgvSettingAll_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        //dgvSettingAll.Invalidate();
        dgvSettingAll.Refresh();
    }
```